# Google Analytic tracking individual page on User Flow

Tags: php, google-analytics

I am having an OpenCart website and I already had Google tracking already. Page views/session tracking runs well without problem. However when I come to "User FLow" from "Behavior" tab in Google Analytic menu, I can only see sessions/views of only /index.php page, not for other pages. What if I want to see how many sessions/pageviews on other specific pages (contact page / product A / product B page?

For example, I have a page which have a link like this: http://..../onlinestore/index.php?route=product/category&path=120

I want to track how many users come to this page or even how many users click on the link which leads to this page, either is ok.

Since Opencart using mvc and routing mechanism or something like that, i cannot track using normal way. I have another html website which I can track specific page easilly by having the tracking code on each individual page. But not on this php page.

Thank you very much.